# A-z Index lising

Tags: php, indexing

Here my table looks like

```
|A Bay of Blood|
|The Adventure|
|Blood River|
|Dooms Day|
|....|
```

I want to show a-z index

```
A B C D E F...... Z
```

and i want to give only clickable link for letter which can be found in table

Comment: You didn't ask anything, just asked for an "out of the box" solution. Did you do any research trying to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
$abc = array ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
foreach ($abc as $v) {
    $ret = $db->query("SELECT COUNT (column) WHERE column LIKE '" .$v. "%'");
    $count = $ret->fetchColumn();
    if ($count == 0) 
        echo '<li>' .$v. '</li>';
    else
        echo '<li><a href="link.php">' .$v. '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: You just add 0 to 9 at the abc array. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use a query like this:

"SELECT column1, column2 FROM yourtable WHERE title LIKE '$letter%'"

... where $letter is A, B or C etc...

Answer (score 0):

Make an array where letters are keys and values are `true` (clickable link) or `false` (just display). Initialize all values to `false`:

```
$letters = array_fill_keys(range('A', 'Z'), false);
```

Loop over the titles and set the value that corresponds to the first letter of each to be `true`:

```
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    $letters[$title[0]] = true;
}
```

Then loop over the result and display a link or just the letter accordingly:

```
foreach ($letters as $letter => $link) {
    if ($link) ...
    else ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe you answered this in its current form. You are obviously in a generous and giving mood today... ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom: Something like that, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.php?alphabet=a">A</a> | <a href="index.php?alphabet=b">B</a> ....

$qry = "select <col_name> from <table_name> where <col_name> LIKE '".$_GET['alphabet']."%'";
```